# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')

Tags: javascript

I do not know why this error occurs when the change event run on the function. Could you tell what is the issue please ?

```js
function clickEvent(event) {
  this.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
    if (node && node === event.target && node.nodeType === 1) {
      node.children[1].click();
    }
  });
}

function changeEvent(event) {
  this.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
    if (node && event.target.files.length) {
      console.log(event.target.dataTransfer.files[0])
    }
  });
}


function eventHandler(element, eventType, callback) {
  return document.getElementById(element).addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
}

eventHandler('app', 'click', clickEvent);
eventHandler('app', 'change', changeEvent);
```

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  padding: 24px;
  gap: 24px;
}

.drop-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px dashed #cccccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.drop-area__prompt {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.drop-area__input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="1" class="drop-area">
    <span class="drop-area__prompt">Click here</span>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="drop-area__input" name="upload"> </div>
  <div id="2" class="drop-area">
    <span class="drop-area__prompt">Click here</span>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="drop-area__input" name="upload"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing that error because `dataTransfer` does not exist on the `target` object for your file events.

[image: JS Error Log]

`event.dataTransfer` is a thing but only for [`drag and drop events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)

You can fix your code by changing this line from

```js
console.log(event.target.dataTransfer.files[0])
```

to

```js
console.log(event.target.files[0])
```

Here are the logs after this fix:

[image: JS Logs after change]

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcayers/t2h8p1en/4/) with the updated code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand now from where this error comes up thank tou